# Azure Deployment of MVC site from Github fails when solution contains Office Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, azure, github

I have a github repo and a solution that's home to:

1. Common C# Library for domain / shared infrastructure
2. C# MVC 5 Web App
3. Xunit Test Project
4. Office App

This repo is connected to an azure site and automatically deploys the MVC Web App project.

Since i've added the Office App to the solution, the automatic deployment is failing with the error below.

```
Command: D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd 
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
Installing 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
Unable to find version '1.1.0' of package 'Microsoft.Office.js'.
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\1.26.30329.722\bin\scripts\nuget.exe" restore "D:\home\site\repository\src\MySolution.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

I'm not really sure as to why this could be happening as it's a pretty generic situation. It's also a perfectly fine nuget package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link shows that the current version is `1.0.1`

> Office Javascript API 1.0.1
>
> The Office JavaScript API includes objects, methods, properties, events, and enumerations that can be used from apps for Office to interact with Microsoft Office 2013 documents or mail items content.

Looking at your error log that contains this line:

> Unable to find version '1.1.0' of package 'Microsoft.Office.js'.

It looks like in some config file you specified to use version `1.1.0`.

Change that to `1.0.1` and it should be fine

Comment: This appears to have fixed it. I did a double check and the config version was wrong. This also appears to be the default version added when creating a new, blank office app in Vs 2013 Update 1. This would mean that package wouldn't ever notify you there's an update via nuget?

Comment: I don't know how that works internally, sorry. But good to hear it's fixed now